# Steady-state analysis of a multiple-input DC-DC converter

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, inductor

I am trying to perform a steady-state analysis of the dual input configuration of the multi-input converter, taken from [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9014953) and shown below:

[image]

The authors state: "*The proposed multi-input converter is depicted in Fig. 3 (a). It consists n pulsating current sources derived from the boost converter, an inductor Lo, a capacitor C1 and a voltage sink that consist a capacitor Co and the load.
The dual-input configuration of this converter is shown in Fig. 3 (b), which is studied and analyzed in this paper. Each of the pulsating current sources includes an inductor (L1- L2), a power switch (S1- S2) and a diode (D1- D2) and are connected to different voltage sources with different voltage levels namely V1– V2. Moreover, the capacitor C1 and the inductor L3 are to ensure the continuity of the output current regardless of the switching scheme.*"

Considering the switching scheme shown below:

[image]

we get the following key waveforms:

[image]

and these are the operating modes of the converter:

[image]

How did the author get these equations:

[image]

Now I have tried to perform steady state analysis by starting with the first state and trying to calculate the inductor voltages and capacitor current. I tried to do that by applying superpositon to make the cicuit simpler. I started by turning Vin1 OFF and got this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fABioP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

but I couldn't get anywhere after that. I understand how to perform steady state analysis for a normal boost converter but I can't figure out what to do with the multiple inductors and capacitors. I don't fully understand what each inductor/capacitor is doing in each of the state or how the circuit works. After finding the equations for the switching states, I want to apply the Capacitor Charge Balance and Volt Second Balance equations to obtain the steady state average equations.

Any insight on how the converter is actually working in the three operating states and how the author got the operating state equations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend you to simulate this circuit first at steady-state then concentrate on the voltage across the inductors. Write the expression of the instantaneous voltage of each inductor and the average must equal 0 V per volt-second balance. From these expressions, you should be able to derive the dc transfer characteristic of this converter.

Comment: FYI, regarding the paper itself: this appears to be roughly equivalent to the usual boost converter with a CLC output filter. They're filtering the boost switches' ground return instead.  That probably makes controlling the switches harder (level shift or isolation needed?); whether it saves any rating on Lo, depends on the desired voltage ratio (:: duty cycle). It strikes me as an academic curiosity; apparently they really love "continuous input and output current". What that has to do with "renewables" I can't discern.

Comment: @VerbalKint I am concentrating on the voltages across the inductors like you suggested, starting with operation mode (a) I have found VL1 and VL2 and VL3 but Im not sure what they are supposed to be in terms of? Should the voltages be only in terms of Vin and VOut or can the equations have VC1 in them for example?

Comment: @TimWilliams I am guessing its because the renewable used in the paper (Solar PV and wind turbine) arent reliable and don't always produce a continuous current.

Comment: @Salman, I would say function of \$V_{in}\$ and \$V_{out}\$ so that you can factor these terms.

Comment: @VerbalKint I got the equations for all three inductors in the three modes of operation, however, I cannot keep them in terms of Vin and Vout only there is always a VC1 term in the equation. Can I perform the volt-second balance with VC1 in the equations?